# Can I set default value in a placeholder if the first property is not null but is empty?

Tags: java, spring, yaml

In the `${property:default}` the value is the value of a property, or if the property is not defined, default is taken.

Is it possible to modify the behavior, maybe using `#{}` instead of `${}`, to take the default also if the property is defined as empty string "" ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use Spring Expression Language (SpEL) to apply default values if the loaded value is empty.

```
@Value("#{'${myProp:}'?.length() == 0 ? 'default value' : '${myProp:}'}")
public String prop;
```

In the above example, `myProp` is a property. You can modify `SpEL` as per your need.

You can improve SpEL to,

```
@Value("#{'${myProp:}' <= '' ? 'default value' : '${myProp:}'}")
```

if the given property contains white spaces, you can trim it down and then check the value.

```
@Value("#{'${myProp:}'?.trim() <= '' ? 'default value' : '${myProp:}'}")
```